Substitute for map_groups
I have a dataframe like this,
session_id | timestamp
abcd | 2024-04-01 
abcd | 2024-04-06
abcd | 2024-04-03
efgh | 2024-04-05
efgh | 2024-04-04
efgh | 2024-04-07

I want to sort it by timestamp in descending, then for each session_id group, the timestamp should be in ascending, currently this is how I achieve this,
df.sort(by="timestamp", descending=True).group_by("session_id", maintain_order=True).map_groups(lambda x: x.sort(pl.col("timestamp"), descending=False))

But is there a substitute to using map_groups
First I sort by descending timestamp, resulting in a df like,
session_id | timestamp
efgh | 2024-04-07
abcd | 2024-04-06
efgh | 2024-04-05
efgh | 2024-04-04
abcd | 2024-04-03
abcd | 2024-04-01 

Then the map_groups,
session_id | timestamp
efgh | 2024-04-04
efgh | 2024-04-05
efgh | 2024-04-07
abcd | 2024-04-01 
abcd | 2024-04-03
abcd | 2024-04-06

The aim is to have recent sessions at the top, and for each of those sessions the rows must be in ascending to track what a particular user did sequentially within a session.

Please give an example before / after DataFrame.

Have updated it

@Hericks's answer gives the same output as the .map_groups for that data. (If you provide examples as runnable code it is much easier for people, df = pl.DataFrame(...) - your df.sort line also contains smartquotes and doesn't run as-is)

Why is group efgh at the top in your example, given that the first session in the group abcd (2024-04-01) was before the first session in group efgh (2024-04-04)?

I think there are two ways to achieve this, based on session start, and session end. The df I have added assumes sorted in descending session_end time, which is 2024-04-07 for efgh, 2024-04-06 for abcd.

So you want session_id sorted by max timestamp descending and timestamp sorted ascending? df.sort(pl.col("timestamp").max().over("session_id"), "timestamp", descending=[True, False]) 

You can compute a temporary extra column that keeps the earliest timestamp for each group, then use a single sort.
df = pl.from_repr("""
shape: (6, 2)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ session_id ┆ timestamp  │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str        ┆ date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ abcd       ┆ 2024-04-01 │
│ efgh       ┆ 2024-04-04 │
│ abcd       ┆ 2024-04-03 │
│ abcd       ┆ 2024-04-06 │
│ efgh       ┆ 2024-04-05 │
│ efgh       ┆ 2024-04-07 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
""")

out = (
    df
       .lazy()
       .with_columns(
           session_start=pl.col.timestamp.min().over("session_id")
       )
       .sort(
           ["session_start", "session_id", "timestamp"],
           descending=[True, False, False]
       )
       .collect()
)

print(out)

Result:
shape: (6, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┐
│ session_id ┆ timestamp  ┆ session_start │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---           │
│ str        ┆ date       ┆ date          │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ efgh       ┆ 2024-04-04 ┆ 2024-04-04    │
│ efgh       ┆ 2024-04-05 ┆ 2024-04-04    │
│ efgh       ┆ 2024-04-07 ┆ 2024-04-04    │
│ abcd       ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 2024-04-01    │
│ abcd       ┆ 2024-04-03 ┆ 2024-04-01    │
│ abcd       ┆ 2024-04-06 ┆ 2024-04-01    │
└────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┘

Make sure that your date column is in fact a pl.Date for optimal speed.

From the documentation of the descending parameter in pl.DataFrame.sort.

descending. [...] When sorting by multiple columns, can be specified per
column by passing a sequence of booleans.

Especially, you can simply do the following.
df.sort("session_id", "timestamp", descending=[True, False])


I think this would sort by the length of session_id. I do not want that, in the final_df the most recent sessions must be at the top, and within those sessions, it should be in ascending order
